# my .htaccess file is not working on XAMPP, but on a webspace

Tags: .htaccess, xampp, webserver

I didn't find any answers describing my problem.

I used to code on a webspace, but now I like to use XAMPP to develop stuff.

Everything is working fine, except my .htaccess file. I copied it from my webserver like the other stuff, but when I try to enter a URL changed by the .htaccess-file, I get a 404 error. I checked the .htaccess file in online tools for errors, but no result.

I checked and `AllowOverride All` is enabled.

I hope you can help me solving this problem.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks +MultiViews -Indexes

# RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
# RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(dist|build|api|js|plugins|sites|templates/.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]*)/([a-z-]*)/?$ index.php?p=$2&sid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]*)/([a-z-]*)/([a-z-]*)/?$ index.php?p=$2/$3&sid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Sample link: `https://localhost/test/test`

Comment: Which sample link you are hitting please do mention here for better understanding of your question.

Comment: added sample link

Comment: Ok where is your htaccess is residing and where is your index.php path wise?

Comment: in the htdocs directory (http://prntscr.com/DMsp3ePV4wPT)

Comment: Both of them in same path you mean?

Comment: yes, they are in the same path

Comment: Ok, could you please check if your `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` us set for same path?

Comment: how could I check whats my DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: maybe that's what you aksed (httpd.conf): DocumentRoot `"G:/XAMPP/htdocs"` and thats my path  `G:\XAMPP\htdocs ` (where the files are)

Answer (score 0):

OK fixed it myself:

don't really know what I did, but just deleted the file, reloaded the page and then create a new file and input the stuff.